# Cryptography textbook

Tags: reference-request, cryptography

Might come as a rather strange request but does anyone know a textbook on cryptography that is small and short, say around 300 pages max. I am tired of having a sore shoulder from carrying 5 heavy math textbooks. Want to carry around a cryptography textbook for anytime reading that is concise but I won't be picky. Just need something light.

Comment: Intro to Cryptography, Mollin; The Mathematics of Ciphers, Coutino; A course in Number Theory and Cryptography, Koblitz

Comment: Get an ebook reader :)

Comment: I do understand your desire for portability. I personally would not recommend reading e-editions of math books. My experience is that the equations often get muddled up. This might be a viable suggestion: the book I mentioned below is excellent. Rather than sacrifice quality for size, you might try a solution I have used in a different context. If you get the paperback edition, you can take it to a copy store. They can cut the binding at places you want, and then bind the separate sections. Of course the book will be in pieces, but will fulfill your requirements and you have a great book

Answer (score 4):

I'll leave the weigh-in to you. But you may be interested in this selected text and course page by an outstanding teacher - Ken Ribet

http://math.berkeley.edu/~ribet/116/

The text is by three also outstanding teachers:
[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Mathematical-Cryptography-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387779930/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1219201611&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387779930)

Comment: *An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography* excellent but it has over 500 pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have a book titled " CRYPTOGRAPHY with CODING THEORY"

By. Wade Trappe, Lawrence C. Washington
ISBN. 0-13-061814-4
Prentice Hall Publications

Has lots of info. Don't see a publication date